# Link against symlink instead of soname

Tags: linux, elf, dynamic-linking

I have an linux application, which on the linker line links against:
libpython2.6.so

This ultimately resolves to libpython.2.6.so.1.0

```
/usr/lib/libpython2.6.so -> libpython2.6.so.1
/usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1 -> libpython2.6.so.1.0
```

Which has SONAME embedded in it so that I am stuck with it linking against the fully versioned name.

```
 g++ foo.cc /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so
 ldd ./a.out | grep python
        libpython2.6.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0 (0x00007fd36f7ab000)
```

This means that my application will ultimately break if there is ever a libpython2.6.so.1.1.  Is there anyway to force my application to use the generic name libpython2.6, instead of libpython2.6.so.1.0?

I use such a small set of the python API, that I think I should be safe linking against a more generic version name of the library.

Comment: And what of any C modules you use?

Comment: My extension is the only part written in C, beside the intepreter.  My only calls are to initialize my functions, take string list arguments for my functions, and  return string values.

Comment: @copumpkin, I haven't looked at this in a long time.  This question looks relevant, but has no answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467163/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-soname-of-a-binary-directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at ``3.1.1. Shared Library Names '' in http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html , this may help you understand the naming method of share library.

> Every shared library has a special
>   name called the `soname''. The soname
>   has the prefix`lib'', the name of
>   the library, the phrase `.so'',
>   followed by a period and a version
>   number that is incremented whenever
>   the interface changes (as a special
>   exception, the lowest-level C
>   libraries don't start with`lib''). A
>   fully-qualified soname includes as a
>   prefix the directory it's in; on a
>   working system a fully-qualified
>   soname is simply a symbolic link to
>   the shared library's ``real name''.
>
> Every shared library also has a ``real
>   name'', which is the filename
>   containing the actual library code.
>   The real name adds to the soname a
>   period, a minor number, another
>   period, and the release number. The
>   last period and release number are
>   optional. The minor number and release
>   number support configuration control
>   by letting you know exactly what
>   version(s) of the library are
>   installed. Note that these numbers
>   might not be the same as the numbers
>   used to describe the library in
>   documentation, although that does make
>   things easier.
>
> In addition, there's the name that the
>   compiler uses when requesting a
>   library, (I'll call it the ``linker
>   name''), which is simply the soname
>   without any version number.

Comment: That the problem.  I need the linker to ignore the soname, and just use the actual filename.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the SO version of libpython2.6 increasing. It will never increase; there won't be any further bugfix releases to 2.6, and even if there were, the SO version would not be increased.

You should rather worry about libpython2.6 going away in future releases of the system (to be replaced by libpython2.7). There isn't any good solution to that, yet; with [PEP 384](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0384/), you will be able to link with libpython3.so.

Comment: Thanks.  That is good information to have.  Python 2.6 is what Mac OS X 10.6, and Ubuntu 10.04 both have at this time.