# Is there any way to change the SONAME of a binary directly？

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, libcurl, binaryfiles

My program depends on `libcurl.so.3`, but in RHEL6 there is no symbolic link `libcurl.so.3 ⇾ libcurl.so.4` (my program can run smoothly when I create this link). However, there is symbolic link `libcurl.so ⇾ libcurl.so.4`.

I would like to modify the `SONAME` embedded in `libcurl.so.3.0.0.0` file from `libcurl.so.3` to `libcurl.so` so that I could run my program on RHEL 6 without creating a symbolic link.

My solution could not be optimal but I think learning how to modify the binary directly is valuable.

```
$readelf -d libcurl.so.3.0.0 

Dynamic segment at offset 0x303cc contains 25 entries:

  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libssl.so.2]
 0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libcurl.so.3]
```

I would like to change `libcurl.so.3` above to `libcurl.so`.

Comment: You could create a copy of "libcurl.so.4", rename it to "libcurl.so.3" and use a hexadecimal editor to rename the SONAME entry from "libcurl.so.4" to "libcurl.so.3". Often this will not work because version information is also present in dynamic libraries.

Comment: I think the easiest way to have that is to rebuild the libcurl and hack a bit the build rules to have the SONAME you want. For post build changes, I would not advice binary edition. There is a project about patching the ELF format http://nixos.org/patchelf.html, it does not allow to change the SONAME, but it can provide some idea on how to implement such a thing.

Answer (score 29):

Yes, you can use [patchelf](https://nixos.org/patchelf.html) like this (from its [Readme](https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf)):

```
patchelf --set-soname libnewname.so.3.4.5 path/to/libmylibrary.so.1.2.3
```

Comment: After using patchelf -set-soname strip on the so now fails: strip: src/.libs/st1B6Gj2: Not enough room for program headers, try linking with -N
strip:src/.libs/st1B6Gj2[.note.gnu.build-id]: Bad value

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid removing the version of the SO object, as for example when your application depends on a specific libc (libc.so.6).

The proper way to do it, if you want to use another lib is using the LD_PRELOAD variable before calling your application

If you set LD_PRELOAD to the path of the new file,  that file will be loaded before any other library (including even C runtime, libc.so).

Comment: It is not about source (library), it is about target (executable) where required SONAME is specified. If you don't have required library, how does `LD_PRELOAD` help?