# Why does *.so have drfferent names in cmakelist and generated executable file?

Tags: c++, cmake

In my cmakelist in linux like

```
target_link_libraries(target-project XXX)
```

**XXX is a thirdpart so file**.And it's real name is libXXX.so in local

and in the generated executable file with `ldd` command, it shows like

```
ldd msgqueue
    YYY.so =>  (0x00007ffdfebda000)
    ...
```

And my question is

1. Where does the infomation with `ldd` come from? i.e. in my example, where does `YYY.so` come from?
2. Does it matter `XXX` in cmakelist and `YYY` in generated executable file with different names?(Of course I will execute `ln -s libXXX.so YYY.so` to make the program executable.)
3. Why does `ldd` generated executable file have the info of `YYY.so` in my example?Generally, it will show as `libYYY.so => ...`, right?Does it matter?Who determines the outcome of `ldd`?

---

**ADDED**
Execute `readelf -d libXXX.so`
it shows like

```
0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [YYY.so]
```

Does it have any refluence with my questions?

Comment: Convention & that's just how cmake, ldd and library loading works.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637841/what-is-the-soname-option-for-building-shared-libraries-for

Comment: Sounds like the soname is incorrect, you should probably just change it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467163/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-soname-of-a-binary-directly